# Override Easy Thumbnails Dango File Type Setting

Tags: django, png, webp, templatetags, easy-thumbnails

While using easy thumbnails in Dango I have set the default file type to webp. It works well. But on occasion I need it to ignore this setting. For example when I render an og image I would like it to stay as a PNG. Would it be possible to add an option to the template tag to use the default uploaded format and ignore the setting in the settings file?

How would I code it, I'm guessing it would be some sort of override to the standard template tag or a new template tag that adds to the old template tag and calls it maybe.